# How to map adjacent elements in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have RDD[String] according to device,timestamp,on/off format.How do I calculate amount of time each device is swiched on.What is the best way of doing this in spark ?

on means 1 and off means 0

E.g

```
A,1335952933,1
A,1335953754,0
A,1335994294,1
A,1335995228,0
B,1336001513,1
B,1336002622,0
B,1336006905,1
B,1336007462,0
```

Intermediate step 1

```
A,((1335953754 - 1335952933),(1335995228 - 1335994294))
B,((1336002622- 1336001513),(1336007462 - 1336006905))
```

Intermediate step 2

```
(A,(821,934))
(B,(1109,557))
```

output

```
(A,1755)
(B,1666)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that RDD[String] can be parsed into a RDD of DeviceLog where DeviceLog is:

```
case class DeviceLog(val id: String, val timestamp: Long, val onoff: Int)
```

The DeviceLog class is pretty straight forward.

```
// initialize contexts
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```

Those initialize the spark context and sql context that we'll use it for dataframes.

**Step 1**:

```
val input = List(
    DeviceLog("A",1335952933,1),
    DeviceLog("A",1335953754,0),
    DeviceLog("A",1335994294,1),
    DeviceLog("A",1335995228,0),
    DeviceLog("B",1336001513,1),
    DeviceLog("B",1336002622,0),
    DeviceLog("B",1336006905,1),
    DeviceLog("B",1336007462,0))

val df = input.toDF()
df.show()
+---+----------+-----+
| id| timestamp|onoff|
+---+----------+-----+
|  A|1335952933|    1|
|  A|1335953754|    0|
|  A|1335994294|    1|
|  A|1335995228|    0|
|  B|1336001513|    1|
|  B|1336002622|    0|
|  B|1336006905|    1|
|  B|1336007462|    0|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Step 2: Partition by device id, order by timestamp and retain pair information (on/off)

```
val wSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")

    val df1 = df
      .withColumn("spend", lag("timestamp", 1).over(wSpec))
      .withColumn("one", lag("onoff", 1).over(wSpec))
      .where($"spend" isNotNull)
    df1.show()

+---+----------+-----+----------+---+
| id| timestamp|onoff|     spend|one|
+---+----------+-----+----------+---+
|  A|1335953754|    0|1335952933|  1|
|  A|1335994294|    1|1335953754|  0|
|  A|1335995228|    0|1335994294|  1|
|  B|1336002622|    0|1336001513|  1|
|  B|1336006905|    1|1336002622|  0|
|  B|1336007462|    0|1336006905|  1|
+---+----------+-----+----------+---+
```

Step 3: Compute upTime and filter by criteria

```
val df2 = df1
      .withColumn("upTime", $"timestamp" - $"spend")
      .withColumn("criteria", $"one" - $"onoff")
      .where($"criteria" === 1)
    df2.show()

| id| timestamp|onoff|     spend|one|upTime|criteria|
+---+----------+-----+----------+---+------+--------+
|  A|1335953754|    0|1335952933|  1|   821|       1|
|  A|1335995228|    0|1335994294|  1|   934|       1|
|  B|1336002622|    0|1336001513|  1|  1109|       1|
|  B|1336007462|    0|1336006905|  1|   557|       1|
+---+----------+-----+----------+---+------+--------+
```

Step 4: group by id and sum

```
val df3 = df2.groupBy($"id").agg(sum("upTime"))
    df3.show()

+---+-----------+
| id|sum(upTime)|
+---+-----------+
|  A|       1755|
|  B|       1666|
+---+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Is there any way to do this only rdd operations without dataframes ?

Comment: I think it can be done, but dataframe offers more flexibility for this kind of problems. Also dataframe seems to be faster, in terms of processing than the rdds.